# The derivative operator is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am finding a proof which proves that the derivative operator is bounded or unbounded (see the Figure, Example 2.1.7 Kendall Atkinson, Weimin Han
Theoretical Numerical Analysis). 
I have proved that $T_1$ is unbounded and hence, it is not continuous. This proof is simple. However, I have a difficulty when considering $T_2$.
Thank you for your support?[image]

Comment: Very strange! I think unboundeeness of $T_1$ is not so obvious but boundedness of $T_2$ is entirely trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|T_2(v)\|=\|v'\|_{C[0,1]}\leq \|v\|_{C[0,1]}+\|v'\|_{C[0,1]}=\||v\|_{C^1[0,1]}$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$||T_2f||_{C[0,1]}=||f'||_{C[0,1]} \le ||f'||_{C[0,1]}+||f||_{C[0,1]}=||f||_{C^1[0,1]}.$$

This gives that $T_2$ is bounded and $||T_2|| \le 1.$